# Help with theorem related to thinning algorithm for point processes simulation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I'm currently self-learning stochastic process and trying to understand the theorem related sampling Poisson process from this [resource](https://www.math.fsu.edu/~ychen/research/Thinning%20algorithm.pdf)

I'm trying to work out the steps of the following theorem from the resource

> Theorem 4.2. Consider a homogeneous Poisson process N¯(t) with
>   intensity function λ¯. Let t¯1,t¯2, . . . ,t¯N¯(T) be the points of
>   the process in the interval (0, T]. Suppose that for 0 ≤ t ≤ T, 0 ≤
>   λ(t) ≤ λ¯. For k = 1, 2, . . . , N¯(T), delete the point t¯k with
>   probability 1 − λ(t¯k)/λ¯; then the remaining points form a point
>   process N(t)

One of the steps in the proof is as follows -

$p_{n} = \int_{a}^{b} \int_{t1}^{b} ... \int_{t_{n-1}}^{b} \prod_{k=1}^{n} \left ( 1 - \frac{\lambda (t_{k})}{\bar{\lambda }} \right ) dt_{1} dt_{2}...dt_{n}$

$
=  \frac{e-^{\bar{\lambda}(b-a)}}{n!}\int_{a}^{b} \int_{a}^{b}...\int_{a}^{b} \prod_{k=1}^{n}(\bar{\lambda } - \lambda (t_{k})) ds_{1} ds_{2}...ds_{n}
$

where
$a \leqslant t1 < ... <  t_{n} \leq b$ and unordered
$\left \{ s_{1},...,s_{n} \right\} = \left \{ t_{1},...,t_{n} \right\}$ and $s_{k}$ takes value in $\left [ a,b \right ]$

**Can someone help me understand the change of variable from t to s, please?**

My intuitive understanding is that since the limit of t is hard to integrate, we construct a variable s which spans the whole space [a,b]. Since there are n! ways of constructing s from t we divide by n!

Answer (score 1):

Yuanda Chen's paper contains a few typos, but the biggest issue here is that you haven't quoted the statement from Yuanda Chen's paper incorrectly.  The correct claim is as follows: let $$p_n=\int_a^b{\int_{t_1}^b{\dots\int_{t_{n-1}}^b{\overline{\lambda}^ne^{-\overline{\lambda}(b-a)}\prod_{k=1}^n{\left(1-\frac{\lambda(t_k)}{\overline{\lambda}}\right)}\,dt_n}\,\dots\,dt_2}\,dt_1}\text{;}$$ then $$p_n=\frac{e^{-\overline{\lambda}(b-a)}}{n!}\int_a^b{\int_a^b{\dots\int_a^b{\prod_{k=1}^n{\left(\overline{\lambda}-\lambda(s_k)\right)}\,ds_n}\,\dots\,ds_2}\,ds_1}$$

With this correction, we can see that most of the change is due to Chen rearranging constants: he is factoring $e^{-\overline{\lambda}(b-a)}$ out of the integrals, and canceling the factors of $\frac{1}{\overline{\lambda}}$ in the denominators of the product.  We thus have, without a change of variable, $$p_n=e^{-\overline{\lambda}(b-a)}\int_a^b{\int_{t_1}^b{\dots\int_{t_{n-1}}^b{\prod_{k=1}^n{\left(\overline{\lambda}-\lambda(t_k)\right)}\,dt_n}\,\dots\,dt_2}\,dt_1}$$

You are correct that the remaining factor of $\frac{1}{n!}$ comes from the ways to make $\{s_k\}_k$ from the $\{t_k\}_k$.  The easiest way I see to write it is to note that we never use the ordering of $\{t_k\}_k$ in the latter expression for $p_n$.  So let $S_n$ act on $[a,b]^n$ in the natural way; then, for all $\sigma\in S_n$, $\sigma$ has constant Jacobian $1$.  Thus \begin{align*}
p_n&=e^{-\overline{\lambda}(b-a)}\int_a^b{\int_{t_{\sigma(1)}}^b{\dots\int_{t_{\sigma(n-1)}}^b{\prod_{k=1}^n{\left(\overline{\lambda}-\lambda\left(t_{\sigma(k)}\right)\right)}\,dt_{\sigma(n)}}\,\dots\,dt_{\sigma(2)}}\,dt_{\sigma(1)}}
\end{align*}  As the $S_n$-orbit of the space of all $\{t_k\}_k$ (the so-called [Weyl chamber](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/18/254a-notes-3b-brownian-motion-and-dyson-brownian-motion/)) is precisely $[a,b]^n$, we obtain \begin{align*}
n!\cdot p_n&=\|S_n\|p_n \\
&=e^{-\overline{\lambda}(b-a)}\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}{\int_a^b{\int_{t_{\sigma(1)}}^b{\dots\int_{t_{\sigma(n-1)}}^b{\prod_{k=1}^n{\left(\overline{\lambda}-\lambda\left(t_{\sigma(k)}\right)\right)}\,dt_{\sigma(n)}}\,\dots\,dt_{\sigma(2)}}\,dt_{\sigma(1)}}} \\
&=e^{-\overline{\lambda}(b-a)}\int_a^b{\int_a^b{\dots\int_a^b{\prod_{k=1}^n{\left(\overline{\lambda}-\lambda(s_k)\right)}\,ds_n}\,\dots\,ds_2}\,ds_1}
\end{align*}

Dividing by $n!$ gives the claimed result.